# Returning output in stored procedures call using LiveCode

Tags: c++, livecode

I have been trying to run stored procedures in LiveCode to return data based on parameters passed to the stored procedure, but I never get anything back when I run with LiveCode's built-in database library. I have also not seen any third-party plug-ins targeted at stored procedures for returning data from MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (also doesn't work for any other DB servers for that matter).

1. Is there a way to run stored procedures in LiveCode?
2. If there are no ways to run stored procedures in LiveCode, can someone point me in the direction of (or help out) writing a LiveCode external for stored procedure calls as a plug-in for LiveCode?.

LiveCode does have an SDK for building externals in C++ and Object-C, but I do not have the required expertise to do that, hence the second question.

Comment: Shouldn't stored procedures be triggered automatically when a specific query is performed? The implementation shouldn't have anything to do with the client application, in this case LiveCode. 
What have you tried to solve this problem and where exactly do you get stuck? What is your LiveCode script? What is your procedure? What kind of output or error message do you get?

Comment: Thank you Mark for your questions, in other to address my earlier question(as well as seeking help on how to write a code to run/call a stored procedure in C++), here goes;

Comment: @Mark
 
    1. I have been trying to run an MS SQL Stored Procedure in LiveCode to return data to use in my stack, **'revDataFromQuery'**, while **'revExecuteSQL'** returns values **'1'** or **'0'**, which understandably means error or run. I have already opened a bug ticket on LiveCode quality center: **bug 13700** please see it further details.

2. My second ask is requesting someone with C++ experience to help write code to run stored procs, i can encapsulate that using LiveCode SDK as an external and this way i will be able to run stored procs from my LiveCode stacks. 

I hope this helps?.